# Software to visually follow the dynamic execution of an exe file, ideally in real-time

Tags: windows

I am very impressed by the way some online malware analysis services (e. g. ANY.RUN, Intezer) offer a sandbox in which they real-time visualize the various steps of execution (e. g. changing to a mutex name, spawning children, establishing an Internet or network connection, etc.) of a given exe file uploaded for analysis.

I find this visualization very useful as it gives you the chance to also take a look at various positions a primary process might save spawns or even relocate itself to.

Does anyone know whether there is a software for Microsoft Windows - sandbox and malware analysis are not required - which lets you visually follow such executional steps? The software can be free of charge or commercial, should be on-premise and real-time "cascade" these steps.

Comment: If the executable was compiled and linked with debugging code embedded, then a debugger program could trace its steps.  But that is something I used as a programmer.  I don't think such a thing exists for executables that were not linked with debugging code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea which is known to me. But a malware coder usually does not do that and still you see this break up and display of the dynamic execution on the mentioned anti-malware cloud platforms - the dynamic analysis of the main executable shows all children processes opened (e. g. malware.exe => cmd.exe => netsh addfirewallrule accept all programs called huihui.exe => huihui.exe.

Comment: This is over my head, but I wonder if you could decompile the executable and analyze the resulting code?  Not quite what you're looking for, but here is an example of software to decompile an execuatble: https://sourceforge.net/projects/decompiler/

Comment: Thank you for your added thought, but I have experience with decompiling and debugging software within and beyond the debug mode. Though that is always the most individual idea, I would like to graphically visualize it or at least build a tree from this execution analysis. When you take a look at where (even legal) software tends to install whatever additional items on your hard disk, and that often where it either should not reside or where you least expect it, it would greatly help me to see from this analysis where I additionally should be looking for.